# launchd - How to skip invocations after waking from sleep?

Tags: macos, launchd

According to the launchd specs, when using the StartCalendarInterval option: "Unlike cron which skips job invocations when the computer is asleep, launchd will start the job the next time the computer wakes up."

But what if I want it to skip the invocation? ie. is there are way to make launchd behave like cron in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

If your program (or a script wrapping round the program) knows when it ought to be run, it could check the system clock when it is run, and, if not in a reasonable window around that time, exit immediately.